# Передача параметров контроллеру Laravel

Tags: laravel

есть код

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
  return 'User '.$id;
});
```

Как изменить кода, чтоб он передал $id контролеру ?

Answer (score 5):

```
Route::get('user/{id}', 'HomeController@user');//HomeController - название контроллера | user - функция в контроллере
```

В контроллере `HomeController`

```
public function user($id) {
  return 'User '.$id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно даже усложнить и передать в контроллер несколько параметров:

```
Route::get('user/{id}/{ip}/{is}', 'HomeController@user');
```

Таким образом можно передать более одного параметра в метод контроллера

```
public function user($id, $ip, $is) { //передаём сразу три параметра
  return $id.$ip.$is;  // выводим результат сложения
}
```

Надеюсь Вам это помогло!) Лайк!)